# File Path Issue Using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

In the client code below I attempt to display an image (space.jpg) which is located in the same directory as index.js and index.html.  The image is showing a broken link when I access the server and am served index.html.  Is there something about Node's native file structure when serving static HTML which I am not taking into account here?

I am testing in a local environment on OS X (10.10.5).

I have the following server code (index.js):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
      console.log('message: ' + msg);
      io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
  console.log('user disconnected');
  });

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

And the following client code (index.html):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Infinium</title>
    <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="chat" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);width:500px;top:0px;left:0px;position:absolute;">
    <div style="width:500px;px;height:100px;overflow-y:auto;color:#FFFFFF" id="messages"></div>
      <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
      </div>
      <img src="space.jpg">

      <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io();

  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });

  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    var element = document.getElementById("messages");
    element.scrollTop = element.scrollHeight;
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did it console log a error message?  what does it say?

Comment: So your issue is that your express server does not serve an image file? Could you then please remove all that chat client code from your question? It's useless clutter. Focus.

Comment: @EliezerWohl Yes, it shows:  GET http://localhost:3000/space.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because when the browser tries to request `space.jpg`, the server won't respond with anything, since you only created a listener for `/` in which you serve your `index.html`.

In order to send your image you will have to add this to your code:

```
app.get('/space.jpg', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./space.jpg');
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [`express.static`](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and set it up for a certain path that contains static content (e.g. images). This will then serve the according file.

Comment: Thank you for the response :)

Answer (score 4):

You have served index.html file but you haven't set up any static file serving functionality in your node.js code.

There is few npm packages for this like **[node-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static)** and **[express-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static)**. You can use this as middleware if you like.

Install any of these in your project as:

$`npm install express-static --save`

Then you can edit your index.js to use express-static as middleware. This will serve all the files under /public in your project root. So, you can put all your assets i.e. images, css, client-side js inside /public directory.

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

var static  = require('express-static');
app.use(static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

In production, it is recommended to use a front facing http server or reverse proxy like **nginx** or **apache** to serve static files since node.js is not good with big resource files.